# What Is a DMC Board on a Alienware System Meant For?

Tags: motherboard

My friend Has Alien-ware 14x machine and it has a DMC board on it. Out of curiosity I want to know what the DMC board is meant for and what is its functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a SiBeam WiHD/DMC controller card. It is used for streaming media to compatible WirelessHD devices. It broadcasts on a separate wireless frequency (60GHz), so it doesn't tie up your normal Wi-fi. It's also faster.

More info & some links:

Thread about the card on [Notebookreview.com](http://forum.notebookreview.com/alienware/576173-m14x-m17xr3-m18x-wireless-hd-sibeam-discussion-thread.html)

More info from Dell [Here.](http://www.dell.com/Learn/us/en/19/help-me-choose/hmc-wireless-hd-sibeam-consumer?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&ref=CFG&delphi:gr=true)

WirelessHD on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WirelessHD)

WiHD Transmitter & Receiver kit on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003HHRENO)